# Cant change line color in histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, graphing

Im generating histograms using gnuplot which works pretty well, but I can't change the color of the bars (anymore).  They just ignore the values I set and use the default values. I'm using this gnuplot script:

```
set terminal png nocrop enhanced font arial 8 size 1024,768
set output '/tmp/output.png'
set border 3 front linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set grid
set grid layerdefault   linetype 0 linewidth 1.500,  linetype 0 linewidth 1.500
set key outside right top vertical Left reverse enhanced autotitles columnhead nobox
set key invert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0
set style histogram rowstacked title  offset character 0, 0, 0
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0
set xtics ("10" 0.00000,"20" 1.00000,"30" 2.00000,"40" 3.00000,"50" 4.00000,"60" 5.00000,"70" 6.00000,"80" 7.00000,"90" 8.00000,"100" 9.00000)
set title "Multi-Histogram"
set ylabel "Meine Y Achse"
set xlabel "X-Achse"
set yrange [ 0 : 100 ] noreverse nowriteback
set ytics(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
i = 5

# SETTING COLOR OF BARS
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "green"
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "yellow"
set style line 3 lt 1 lc rgb "red

plot '/tmp/9619555_data.dat' using (100.*$2/$24):(0.5):($2>0?1:2):xtic(1) w boxes lc variable, for [i=2:4] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(5)) title column(i)
```

This is my datafile:

```
X       leicht  mittel  stark   total
1       20      60      20      100
2       10      30      60      100
3       30      35      35      100
4       20      60      20      100
5       90      5       5       100
6       25      25      50      100
7       33      33      34      100
8       10      10      80      100
9       40      20      40      100
10      70      5       25      100
```

Everything beside the colors of the bars works for me,... what am I doing wrong with the style?

Comment: What is the `**` doing in your with statement?  (`**w`)

Comment: upps I wanted to highligth the section but it doenst work but I forgot to delte the `**`

Comment: I haven't had time to really investigate this yet.  However, this other answer of mine might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664797/gnuplot-each-histogram-bar-with-different-color/11669631#11669631

Comment: Yea I already found that post but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `set` command to set the color. If you just say `plot "yourdata.file" lc 0` you are all done. Keep in mind that in gnuplot the colors can be written as numbers from 0-7, you don't need to write the name of the color.